# After click on button in Form append html page by Ajax

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

I am using Jquery mobile frame work and also new in jquery mobile. I want to append one html page by Ajax. First i am taking one button(check) in form but whenever click on this button then page appended but layout will be damage. I don't know how to append HTML page by ajax in jquery mobile.

SCREEN SHOT FOR HINTS:

1. This page is before click on check button:
   [image]
2. After click on Check button:
   [image]

HTML CODE:

```
 <form id="checkPinCode1" method="get" data-uri="<c:url value="/pincode-available/${product.productId}/${product.productOfCityId}"/>" data-ajax="false"> 
        <div  style="margin-bottom: 20px; width: 80%;">
            <input name="pinCode" type="number"   class="form-control pinCode" placeholder=" Enter pincode here..">   
        </div>
        <div  style="margin-bottom: 20px; width:40%;">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Check">Check</button>
        </div>
</form>


<div id="showPincodeAvailablity"> 
<%--APPEND PAGE HERE--%>
</div>
```

AJAX CODE:

```
 $.ajax({
                    type: 'get',
                    url: url,
                    data: {pincode: pincode},
                    success: function (response) {
                        if (response.success === "true") {  
                            $("#showPincodeAvailablity").html(response.html);    
                        }                       
                    },
                    error: function (response) {                      
                    },
                    complete: function (response) {
                    }
                });
```

JAVA CODE:

```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/pincode-available/{productId}/{productOfCityId}", method = {RequestMethod.GET})
        @ResponseBody
    <%--- CODE LINE 1--%>
 <%--- CODE LINE 2--%>
 <%--- CODE LINE .....--%>
     resp.put("success", "true");
                resp.put("html", html);

            }
```

First i am type pin code and click on check button then check button control go to the controller  and comes into the ajax then page append by id = showPincodeAvailablity. and page appended but page layout is not comes proper way. Give me some idea for achieving this solution.

Comment: It should be appended inside form right ?

Comment: It is appends. But Layout is not comes proper way..

Comment: It would be great If you could provide a fiddle of the same..

Comment: It is not possible. But you have any idea append the page then let me know. could you create JSfiddle for append page after click form button.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line

```
$("#showPincodeAvailablity").html(response.html);
```

to this

```
$("#showPincodeAvailablity").html(response.html).enhanceWithin();
```

Comment: Creating a jsfiddle would be great for us to debug through your code